# Check if multiple strings are in another string

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm making a chat bot that looks out for specific terms in order to make relevant responses, but I'm struggling with finding a way to find key words from a string.

I've already tried using `word.find()` and `word in str` but I may have made an issue somewhere among those.

```
while True:
    user = input("what's up?")
    if "sad" or "unhappy" or "depressed" in user:
        print("oh that's quite sad")
    else:
        print("that's good")
```

No matter what I type it constantly returns "oh that's quite sad".

Comment: `if "sad" in user or "unhappy" in user or "depressed" in user:`

Comment: [How to test multiple variables against a value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15112125)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
while True:
    user = input("what's up?")
    if "sad" in user or "unhappy" in user or "depressed" in user:
        print("oh that's quite sad")
    else:
        print("that's good")
```

### **Solution 2: using `any`**

Define in advance the strings and use this:

```
mylist = ["sad","unhappy","depressed"]
```

```
while True:
    user = input("what's up?")
    if any([x in user for x in mylist]):
        print("oh that's quite sad")
    else:
        print("that's good")
```